# FBinfer in Maven using gitlab pipelines error: unmappable character (0xE2) for encoding US-ASCII

Tags: maven

I am seeing an issue with maven using Fbinfer using gitlab pipelines using linux runner

> [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding
> ANSI_X3.4-1968, i.e. build is platform dependent
>
> [ERROR] /build/app/hello.java [43,43] error: unmappable charater
> (0xE2] for encoding US-ASCII

Fbinfer maven command used:

```
/infer capture -- mvn clean compile
```

Comment: The problem is simply: `[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding ANSI_X3.4-1968, i.e. build is platform dependent` that you have not set the encoding... see https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning

Answer (score 0):

Pure ASCII is 7 bit only, meaning that characters above 127 are illegal. `0xE2` is a hexadecimal representation of 226 which is above 127, hence the error.

You need to tell which encoding system to use when interpreting the bytes. A common choice is ISO-Latin-1 - see https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html if it looks right to you

Then change in your Pom to reflect that. Look for “ascii” to see where.

Notice that keeping your project 7-bit clean is a good thing to avoid encoding issues.